# Checking if the parenthesis in a expression are balanced using vector

Tags: c++, vector, stack

I am trying to check if a string of parenthesis is balanced. I am trying to use vectors in c++ for the same. The output should be the size of the vector and if the size is 0, the string is balanced and if it is not it is not balanced. However I get a blank output for the code below.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    int j;
    vector<char>a;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i+=1){
        a.push_back(s[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i+=1){
        if (a[i]=='(') {
            j=i;
            while(a[j]!=')')
                j+=1;
        } else if(a[j]==')') {
            a.erase(a.begin()+i);
            a.erase(a.begin()+j);
        }
    }
}
cout<<a.size();
return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be the number of elements in string apart from the parenthesis. However I do not get any output for this program. I suspect the problem is with the erase function of vector.

Comment: I've edited your code to make the blocks of code visible. Can you spot the error by yourself now? The compiler error you will get is `error: 'j' was not declared in this scope` on line with `else if`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks for pointing out that to me. However I still can't get any output when I'm running the program after editing the program to give j a proper scope.

Comment: Why do you need to use a vector?  Simply (1)  set a count to zero   (2) iterate over all characters in the string, from first to last doing (3)  Whenever a `'('` is encountered, increment the counter, and whenever a `')'` is encountered, decrement the counter.   If the count goes negative, the string is unbalanced.  (4)   After iterating over all characters, the string is balanced if the count is zero, otherwise it is unbalanced.

Comment: @Peter Actually this code is a part for a bigger program of checking if the brackets in a string are balanced(including {,(,[). So if I have a ' ) ' appear before '('.The end result would still show me that it's balanced based on the method you are recommending. Hence I am using vectors

Answer (score 0):

I would google first. Anyway this is a qoute from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)

> Erase elements Removes from the vector either a single element
> (position) or a range of elements ([first,last)).
>
> This effectively reduces the container size by the number of elements
> removed, which are destroyed.
>
> Because vectors use an array as their underlying storage, erasing
> elements in positions other than the vector end causes the container
> to relocate all the elements after the segment erased to their new
> positions.

So i would say yes